# Get "locked orientation", also known as "view orientation"

Tags: ios, orientation

I have locked the orientation via XCode to be either landscape-left and landscape-right, but using  `UIDevice.current.orientation` is giving the orientation as if it was not locked. Like when I am physically (in real life) in portrait, but my view is locked in landscape-left, I want to still get `landscape-left`, is this possible?

I can of course get the non-specific orientation by testing if width > height. But i needed the specific orientation of either `landscape-left` or `-right`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of asking the *device* for its orientation, ask the *app* for its orientation, by asking for `UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation`.

Comment: Works!! Thank you! By any chance would you know Android equivalent? (I didnt start searching yet, but just trying my luck to see if I can save some searching haha)